# crystal report sum group within another group

Tags: crystal-reports

I have tbInvoice with VESSEL, ETA, AMOUNT something like this:

[image]

and in CR, i have group ETA under VESSEL like this :

[image]

I have @total as formula in CR like this :

Sum ({tbInvoice.AMOUNT}, {tbInvoice.VESSEL})

and the result is like this :

[image]

What i want is result like this :

[image]

Which part i have to modify? Pls Help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Sum ({tbInvoice.AMOUNT}, {tbInvoice.VESSEL})
```

to

```
Sum ({tbInvoice.AMOUNT}, {tbInvoice.ETA})
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. It gets error "There must be a group that match this field."

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :
I create Sum(AMOUNT) in ETA section in CR.
No need Formula or Running Total.

Thanks.

Comment: The 2nd argument in a SUM formula is the field/formula you are grouping on. Evidently you were grouping on something else at level 2. Creating a SUM field instead of a formula is just another mechanism for achieving the same thing.  In fact, if you open the formula editor and look at the list of objects in the report fields, you will see your Sum field listed as a Sigma object. If you double-click that object to insert it into the formula expression, it would show the full syntax, with the 2nd argument as the group field.